# Change color of input text field not working

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong, but why when I test the regular expression `/^[\d{9}]*$/` on the website https://regex101.com/#javascript it match correctly if it's a number or not, but when I apply the RegEx on the JavaScript it doesn't work properly? I mean, its only showing red for numeric or characters. Instead green for numeric and red for characters.
HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="age" id="msisdn" onKeyUp="checkKey()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkKey() {
    var msisdn = document.getElementById("msisdn");

    if (msisdn.value == /^[\d{9}]*$/) {
        msisdn.style.color = "#00b300";
    } else {
        msisdn.style.color = "#ff0000";
    }
}
```

[Code on fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/h05hgf3g/10/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if(msisdn.value == /^\d{9}$/) {` will compare the input value(*string*) against RegExp Object which will always return `false`.

Use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```
if(/^\d{9}$/.test(msisdn.value)) {
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hygfrykg/)

And here's the shortest equivalent code

```
msisdn.style.color = /^\d{9}$/.test(document.getElementById("msisdn").value)
    ? "#00b300"
    : "#f00";
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/r39wn1gc/)

---

JavaScript is not needed just to change the color of the text when it is not following the regex, HTML & CSS can be used. HTML5 `pattern` attribute can be used on the `<input>` and `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-selectors can be used in the CSS.

```css
input:invalid {
  color: #f00;
}
input:valid {
  color: #00b300;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="msisdn" name="plaintext" pattern="\d{9}">
```